# R Generate a data frame based on several called REST URLs

Tags: r, html-table

hope you can help me out.

I have the following case:

I want to call a REST URL. This URL is limited to it´s max. amount of rows. Therefore I wrote a function which gives me the total number of calls.

Then I identified the different REST URLs I must call. They differentiate on the page-num. In my example I will have 9 different REST URLs, so page-num=1, page-num=2,..., page-num=9

I have to call all 9 REST URLs to get the whole data.

```
# Rowcount of the REST URL
rowcount <- readHTMLTable(getURL("https://apirest/html/getRowCount&max-results=10000&apikey=123"),
                          stringAsFactors = FALSE, header = FALSE, which = 1, colClasses = c("character","integer"))

# Number of needed Calls of the Rest URL
Calls <- round(as.numeric(as.character(rowcount[,2]))/10000+1)

# Output of different REST URLS
DfCall<-as.data.frame(matrix(NA),nrow=Calls)
for(i in 1:Calls){
  DfCall[i,]<-paste0("https://apirest&max-results=10000&page-num=",i,"&apikey=123")
}
```

So far so good.

But I can't find a proper method which enables me to call all of the 9 REST URLs and bind them together to one "master" data frame (row by row).

Please forgive me but I'm not allowed to show the whole REST URL due to data privacy.

Thank you for any help!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
1:Calls %>% 
     purrr::map(~ paste0("https://apirest&max-results=10000&page-num=",.,"&apikey=123")) %>% 
     purrr::map(~ xml2::read_html(.) %>% rvest::html_table(fill = T)) %>% 
     dplyr::bind_rows()
```

EDIT:
Explaining how it works.

The `%>%` or pipe operator works by passing (or piping) the results of a function call to another function, thereby limiting the creation of temporary variables.

`purrr::map` takes a list and applies a function to each member of that list. So for each integer in `1:Calls` it calls `paste0` creating your url string. Putting a `~` before your function within the `map` call is a bit of syntactical sugar that allows you to use the `.` placeholder as a proxy for each element of your list that is being passed in.

So in the case of `purrr::map(~ paste0("https://apirest&max-results=10000&page-num=",.,"&apikey=123")`, the `.` becomes each integer in `1:Calls`. So in the first iteration it's `1`, then `2` and so on.

When the first `purrr::map` is done you now have a list of url strings.  This list of strings is then piped to another `purrr::map` whose function takes a url string and returns a `dataframe` by reading the html of the url link and extracting the table from it.  You can replace this code with whatever code you like that takes your url string as an input and returns your desired `dataframe`.

After this step you have a list of dataframes.  That list is then piped to `dplyr::bind_rows()` which combines all the dataframes in your list into one dataframe.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain how your code would work?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a for loop but this doesn't work. The problem is that the Result2 gets always overwritten with the last page:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(DfCall)){

    #API call execution
    APIResults<-readHTMLTable(getURL(DfCall[i,]),
                              stringAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, which = 1, colClasses = c("character","character","integer"))

    #Storage of the results in a data frame
    Result2<-rbind(Result,APIResults)

  }
```

Is there a way to avoid this overwrite issue?